# Oracle DAC Email Configuration: Access to default session denied

Tags: java, oracle, email, etl, business-intelligence

When I tried to configure Email recipients on Oracle DAC, I just got an Error like the picture below.

DAC Email Configuration:
[image: DAC Email Configuration]

```
This email could not be completely sent! Please inspect the stack-trace below, and inform the DAC administrator
java.lang.SecurityException: Access to default session denied
at javax.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(Session.java:311)
at com.siebel.etl.email.EmailManager.dispatchJMail(EmailManager.java:461)
at com.siebel.etl.email.EmailManager.dispatch(EmailManager.java:394)
at com.siebel.etl.email.EmailTest.sendTestEmail(EmailTest.java:72)
at com.siebel.etl.email.EmailTest.sendTestEmail(EmailTest.java:54)
at com.siebel.etl.gui.login.EmailConfigPanel.sendTestEmail(EmailConfigPanel.java:170)
at com.siebel.etl.gui.login.EmailConfigPanel$EmailTestAction.doOperation(EmailConfigPanel.java:225)
at com.siebel.etl.gui.view.dialogs.WaitDialog.doOperation(WaitDialog.java:53)
at com.siebel.etl.gui.view.dialogs.WaitDialog$WorkerThread.run(WaitDialog.java:85)
```

The Email address, password and the port is correct.

Who can tell me what can I do for that? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    session = Session.getInstance  -- gets the session not default
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't modified DAC's source code. Can I fix it by configuration?